# how to get whole line text, on which I got cursor

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How to get text of whole line, on which I got cursor. I guess I have to do something with `region1` for it:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class line_text_plugin__Command(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):            
        print('line_text_plugin__ called')
        view = self.window.active_view()
        region1 = view.sel()[0]

        # lineText = how to get whole line text, on which I got cursor
```

... but I don't know how to convert `region1` to line text.

`region1` in my code is region of first selection.

This plugin should work as following:
For example if I got cursor on 6th row...
[image: cursor on middle 6th line, sublime 3]
... it must return string `view = self.window.active_view()`

Comment: I don't think the current cursor position is the same thing as the current selection(s) -- sublime allows several of those at one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want something like:

```
view = self.window.active_view()
line = view.line(view.sel()[0])
linetext = view.substr(line)
```