# code for getting nearest to cursor word

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I develop plugin for `sublme text 3`. I need code for getting nearest to cursor word.

For example if I got cursor as on image...

[image: how to get nearest to cursor word]

... this plugin should return word `run`

....or at least number `10` which corresponds position of char `u` in line `4`:

And then I will be able to get word `run` from number `10` and text of line `4`.

But now I only can get `linetext` on which I got cursor:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class line_nearest_to_cursor_wordCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):            
        print('line_nearest_to_cursor_word called')
        view = self.window.active_view()
        region1 = view.sel()[0]
        line = view.line(region1)
        linetext = view.substr(line)
        print(linetext)
```

When I print `region1` it gives two numbers, but they are wierd:

```
    print (region1) # prints (113, 113), but 113 is not position of char "u" in line "    def run(self):"
```

So problem reduced to writing method `getXcoordPositionOnLine`...

```
    xCoord = getXcoordPositionOnLine(region1) 
    print xCoord
```

... which will give me x position of cursor on line.

Or maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19714517/416467) for you yesterday. Looking at the docs, if you simply replace `line` in yesterday's answer with `word`, I believe you will get what you are looking for.

```
view = self.window.active_view()
word = view.word(view.sel()[0])
wordtext = view.substr(word)
```

As @skuroda suggests, this is easily answered by looking at the documentation. It isn't that difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Though I suppose the formatting leaves something to be desired, please try to take a look at the API documentation. A large number of your questions can likely be answered by exploring the docs. These are available [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) for ST3. With that being said, take a look at `view#word(point)` and `view#word(region)` in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think `region1` being `(113, 113)` means, how you might be able to use it with the API to get what you want, or at least provide you with enough information to be able to write something like a `getXcoordPositionOnLine()` function yourself.

The [API documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) says a `sublime.Region` has two properties, `a` and `b`, which represent the first and second **ends** of the region. I believe these are just two integer offsets from the beginning of the text buffer, and the reason they're the same in this case is because the region is empty (i.e. no characters are actually selected by it since they're the same value, which mean it's effectively the position of a cursor).

To illustrate that below is a screenshot of the code snippet shown in your question in another editor in which I've selected all the text from the beginning to the point between the "r" and the "u" in the word "run". This editor has an indicator near the bottom right that shows shows the total of Bytes/Lines currently selected. Notice that this is displaying 113/4 -- meaning that the "r" is 113<sup>th</sup> character in the text buffer and it's on the 4<sup>th</sup> line because there are 3 newline characters preceding it.

[image: screenshot of the code snippet shown another editor]
`sublime.Region`s also have an **xpos** property which sounds like it represents the offset of the character from the last newline (and would be something like 10 in this case I guess). Further reading of the documentation leads me to suspect you might be able to get the closest word to the cursor represented by `region1` is the value returned from `view.substr(view.word(region1)`.